# How do I enable syntax highlighting for "restructuredtext"?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

At first, the top-ranked Google search answer points to an outdated answer: [Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints)

[Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) is gone ...

The language hint: `<!-- language: restructuredtext -->` doesn't work; neither do `rest` or `rst`.

So how do I hint Stack Overflow to highlight ReST, because `restructuredtext` is not recognized.

**<!-- language: restructuredtext -->**

```
.. directive:: Title
   :option: foo

My example text :role:`spam <egg>` goes here.
```

**<!-- language: rest -->**

```
.. directive:: Title
   :option: foo

My example text :role:`spam <egg>` goes here.
```

**<!-- language: rst -->**

```
.. directive:: Title
   :option: foo

My example text :role:`spam <egg>` goes here.
```

So how do I highlight ReST markup texts?

Comment: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Why would any new computing standard try to use "rest" as an acronym at this point? It's like calling it AjAX or something...

Comment: It's gone?  It appears to be at the other end of the link.  And nothing there states this new language is supported, so I'm not sure why you think it would... If you're FRing for support, then (as per the link above) you should open an issue at GitHub. Or, if you're cool, do it yourself and submit a pull request.

Comment: @Will I can't submit pull requests and bug fixes to all GitHub projects where I find issues ... The day has a limited number of hours.

Comment: You can certainly submit this issue on GitHub.

Comment: Don't get me wrong... I'm doing a lot of open source work since 2 years :) But I'm a bit frustrated with projects around Sphinx. These packages are full of issues. So I wrote > 20 issues in the last 14 days. I'll submit an issue and ask for ReST :)